# Extrair objetos em Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic, websql

Estou tentando pegar os dados selecionados de um `Checkbox` no Ionic.

Minha *View* está assim com o `CheckBox`:

```
<ion-view view-title="Comprar Bebidas Adicionais" hide-nav-bar="false">

    <div class="bar bar-subheader">
        <h2 class="title">{{'Sub-Total R$ ' + getTotalSelected() }}</h2>
    </div>

    <ion-content delegate-handle="top" lazy-scroll id="lista-bebidas" class="has-header lista-bebidass" ng-controller="exBebidasCtrl">

        <ion-refresher pulling-text="Puxe para atualizar..." on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>
        <ion-list class="card list">
            <div class="item item-input">
                <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" aria-label="filter bebidasextras" />
            </div>
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list>

            <div ng-repeat="bebida in bebidasextras">
                <ion-checkbox ng-model="bebida.selected" ng-checked="bebida.selected">
                    <h2>{{bebida.ad_bebida_titulo}}</h2>
                    <p>R$ {{bebida.ad_bebida_valor}}</p>
                </ion-checkbox>
            </div>

        </ion-list>

        <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="updateBebida()">
                        Continuar Comprando
                    </button> {{ selectedItems | json }}

    </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Este JSON estou imprimindo na tela só pra ver se pegou mesmo.

E meu *Controller* está assim:

```
.controller("exBebidasCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicScrollDelegate, $http, $httpParamSerializer, $stateParams, $timeout, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $ionicPopover, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicHistory, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion, sharedCartService, CartServiceBebidasEx, $location, DBLocal) {

            // VERIFICA SE HÁ BEBIDAS EXTRAS

            $scope.bebidasextras = [];

            var promise = $http.get('http://nhac.esy.es/api_carrinho/lista_bebida_extra.php?json=restaurantes')
                .success(function(retorno) {
                    console.log(retorno);
                    $scope.bebidasextras = retorno; // não precisa fazer retorno.data

                    $scope.user = {
                        bebidasextras: [$scope.bebidasextras[1]]
                    };
                    $scope.checkAll = function() {
                        $scope.user.bebidasextras = angular.copy($scope.bebidasextras);
                    };
                    $scope.uncheckAll = function() {
                        $scope.user.bebidasextras = [];
                    };
                    $scope.checkFirst = function() {
                        $scope.user.bebidasextras = [];
                        $scope.user.bebidasextras.push($scope.bebidasextras[0]);
                    };
                    $scope.setToNull = function() {
                        $scope.user.bebidasextras = null;
                    };



                    // CALCULA TOTAL DOS ITENS SELECIONADOS NA LISTA
                    $scope.sub = function(i) {
                        i.quantity--;
                    }

                    $scope.add = function(i) {
                        i.quantity++;
                    }

                    $scope.getTotalSelected = function() {
                        var total = 0;

                        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.bebidasextras.length; i++) {
                            var bebida = $scope.bebidasextras[i];
                            total += bebida.selected ? Number(bebida.ad_bebida_valor) : 0;
                        }


                        return total;
                    }

                })
                .error(function(erro) {
                    console.log(erro);
                });


            // PEGA BEBIDAS SELECIONADAS      
            $scope.updateBebida = function() {
                var p = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.bebidasextras.length; i++) {
                    var item = $scope.bebidasextras[i];
                    console.log(item);
                    if (item.selected) {
                        p.push(item)
                    }

                }

                $scope.selectedItems = p;
                console.log(p);

                var titulo = data.filter(function(e) {
                    return e.titulo_promo == p.ad_bebida_titulo
                    conlole.log(titulo);
                })


                // TESTA SE GUARDA A BEBIDA SELECIONADA

                // INSERINDO DADOS LOCALMENTE
                DBLocal.localdb();

                //            var len = $scope.p.ad_bebida_titulo;
                //            console.log(len);

                //          var dados =  p.filter(function(e){
                //              return e.ad_bebida_titulo == bebida.ad_bebida_titulo;
                //          })

                DBLocal.db.transaction(function(res) {
                    res.executeSql("INSERT INTO AD_BEBIDAS (nome_bebida_ad) VALUES(?);", [p.ad_bebida_titulo]);
                });



            }
```

(Meio bagunçado, mas comentei) Observe que quero armazenar os dados do `checkbox` selecionado num WEBSQL, mas não estou conseguindo pegar, veja o console dele:

[image: Console com os dados]

Não sei pegar os dados deste objeto para jogar no meu banco de dados local. Ali em:

```
DBLocal.db.transaction(function(res){
    res.executeSql("INSERT INTO AD_BEBIDAS (nome_bebida_ad) VALUES(?);",[p.ad_bebida_titulo]);
```

Como posso pegar esses dados?

Comment: Primeira coisa que percebi é que na sua view tem `ng-model="bebida.selected"` mas no controller so encontrei `$scope.bebidasextras`. Ate vi que ter uma variavel bebida `var bebida = $scope.bebidasextras[i];` mas essa variavel `bebida` não esta no `$scope`, portanto invisível/inacessível para a sua view.

Comment: Mas está listando os produtos na View, coloquei bebida.selected devido ao ng-repeat: ng-repeat="bebida in bebidasextras"

Comment: Tá inclusive capturando o que foi selecionado, mas não sei pegar os objects, como na imagem.

Comment: Mau ai nao vi o ng-repeat, passou batido.
Não seria por que a variavel `p` é um array? Logo `p. ad_bebida_titulo` nao existe, mas `p[0].ad_bebida_titulo` existe.

Comment: Exatamente isso! Obrigado Neuber!

Comment: adicionei como resposta para facilitar a vida de quem chegar mais tarde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua variavel `p`é um array.

Aqui nesse trecho de codigo

```
DBLocal.db.transaction(function(res){
          res.executeSql("INSERT INTO AD_BEBIDAS (nome_bebida_ad) VALUES(?);", [p.ad_bebida_titulo]);              
});
```

Você esta tentando acessar a propriedade `ad_bebida_titulo` do objeto `Array`, como ela não existe você acaba recebendo um `undefined`.

Para dar certo teria que ser algo do tipo:

```
// PEGA BEBIDAS SELECIONADAS      
$scope.updateBebida = function() {
    var p = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.bebidasextras.length; i++) {
        var item = $scope.bebidasextras[i];
        console.log(item);
        if (item.selected) {
            p.push(item)
        }

    }

    $scope.selectedItems = p;
    var item;

    //aqi vai percorrer todo o conteudo da vriavep p, poderia ate dar
    //uma otimaizada e deixar junto com o p.push(item), ai "economiza" um for
    for(var i in p){
        item = p[i];
        console.log(item);
        var titulo = data.filter(function(e) {
            return e.titulo_promo == item.ad_bebida_titulo
            conlole.log(titulo);
        })


        // TESTA SE GUARDA A BEBIDA SELECIONADA

        // INSERINDO DADOS LOCALMENTE
        DBLocal.localdb();

        DBLocal.db.transaction(function(res) {
            res.executeSql("INSERT INTO AD_BEBIDAS (nome_bebida_ad) VALUES(?);", [item.ad_bebida_titulo]);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Neuber!

Comment: Neuber, só mais uma questão, se puder ajudar...

Comment: Aqui tá pegando só o primeiro que seleciona nos checkBoxes, como posso buscar todos que estão pegando no CheckBox?

Comment: editei a resposta ve la, acho que agora ta mais facil de entender

Comment: Em "var titulo = data.filter(function(e) { " o "data" seria o "p"? Pergunto porque não foi definido...

Comment: É isso mesmo. Troquei o filter pelo p...

Comment: Mas ele continua registrando apenas 1 registro. Se o usuário escolher mais de um, ele manda só o último selecionado.

Comment: Oi Neuber, resolvi mudar o esquema de telas que não estava funcionando bem, abri um novo post, que apesar de parecido é diferente... Segue o link, se puder ajudar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149472/adicionar-itens-ao-banco-de-dados-local-conforme-ir-selecionando-na-lista

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado! Estou voltando só pra agradecer. Valeu mesmo! :))